# androidでのcookieManagerを使ったクッキーの保存

Tags: android, java

## やりたいこと

Androidからウェブサーバーにpostリクエストをし、 
クッキーを保存するようなアプリを作ろうとしています。 
(postのパラメータは、未実装です)

アクティビティを破棄しなければ、下記のコードでクッキーを保存し、渡すことができました。 
ただ、一度アプリを落とすとクッキーが消えてしまっています。

色々と調べてみましたが、原因がよく分かりません。 
sharedPreferencesなどに保存して、毎回取り出す必要があるのでしょうか。

Androidは初心者ですが、ご教授いただけると幸いです。 
よろしくお願いいたします。

## コード

```
package com.example.test;

import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.text.TextUtils;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.HttpCookie;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;

public class HttpResponsAsync extends AsyncTask < Void, Void, String > {

    private TextView textView;
    static final String COOKIES_HEADER = "Set-Cookie";
    static java.net.CookieManager msCookieManager = new java.net.CookieManager();

    private Context context = null;
    private ProgressDialog dialog = null;
    private String title;
    private String msg;

    /**
     * コンストラクタ
     */
    public HttpResponsAsync(Context context) {
        super();
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        // doInBackground前処理
    }

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void...params) {
        String readSt = null;


        HttpURLConnection con = null;
        URL url = null;
        String urlSt = "https://URL.com";

        try {
            // URLの作成
            url = new URL(urlSt);
            // 接続用HttpURLConnectionオブジェクト作成
            con = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            if (msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies().size() > 0) {
                //While joining the Cookies, use ',' or ';' as needed. Most of the server are using ';'
                con.setRequestProperty("Cookie",
                    TextUtils.join(";", msCookieManager.getCookieStore().getCookies()));
            }

            // リクエストメソッドの設定
            con.setRequestMethod("POST");
            // リダイレクトを自動で許可しない設定
            con.setInstanceFollowRedirects(false);
            // URL接続からデータを読み取る場合はtrue
            con.setDoInput(true);
            // URL接続にデータを書き込む場合はtrue
            con.setDoOutput(true);

            // 接続
            con.connect();
            Map < String, List < String >> headerFields = con.getHeaderFields();
            List < String > cookiesHeader = headerFields.get(COOKIES_HEADER);

            if (cookiesHeader != null) {
                for (String cookie: cookiesHeader) {
                    msCookieManager.getCookieStore().add(null, HttpCookie.parse(cookie).get(0));
                }
            }

            InputStream in = con.getInputStream();
            readSt = readInputStream( in );


        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return readSt;
    }

    public String readInputStream(InputStream in ) throws IOException,
    UnsupportedEncodingException {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        String st = "";

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader( in , "UTF-8"));
        while ((st = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(st);
        }
        try { in .close();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return sb.toString();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);
        // doInBackground後処理
        JSONArray jsonArray = null;
        try {
            // 配列を取得する場合
            jsonArray = new JSONObject(result).getJSONArray("data");
            int count = jsonArray.length();
            JSONObject[] bookObject = new JSONObject[count];
            for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                bookObject[i] = jsonArray.getJSONObject(i);
                // String型の場合
                String st = bookObject[i].getString("type");
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Cookieの永続化には一手間必要です。
OkHttpなど使用されているHttp Clientによって選択も変わりますので
「android cookie persistent」で検索されるといろいろ見つかります。